# Relationship between rospkg and catkin_pkg (& ament_package)

Tags: ros, ros2, rospkg, catkin-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIUC currently [rospkg](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/python_api.html) and [catkin_pkg](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/catkin_pkg/) provide Python API for package info handling in ROS1. I'm willing to add an API, which I mainly target `catkin` pkgs with at the moment but should theoretically be able to handle `ament` or even rosbuild pkgs as well, and thus can be essentially called manifesto-format agnostic. Then I wonder which package is the right place to add that kind of change.

Current released version of `rospkg` and `catkin_pkg` seem to be independent (see below the system output). But a [bug fix PR to rospkg](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/pull/134) introduced a dependency to `catkin_pkg`, so at the moment dependency tree for Python API pkg is `catkin_pkg <- rospkg` (excluded ament for now as I'm not yet sure about it). This makes me slightly lean toward opening a PR to catkin_pkg, but I'm not entirely sure (as the portion of the code in rospkg that depends on catkin_pkg is very limited).

Where's the best place would be?

```
$ apt-cache depends python-rospkg
python-rospkg
  Depends: python
  Depends: python
  Depends: python-yaml
  Depends: python-rospkg-modules
  Conflicts: python3-rospkg
$ apt-cache depends python-catkin-pkg
python-catkin-pkg
  Depends: python
  Depends: python
  Depends: python-docutils
  Depends: python-dateutil
  Depends: python-pyparsing
  Depends: <python-argparse>
    libpython2.7-stdlib
  Depends: python-catkin-pkg-modules
  Conflicts: catkin
  Conflicts: python3-catkin-pkg
$ apt-cache policy python-rospkg
python-rospkg:
  Installed: 1.1.4-100
  Candidate: 1.1.4-100
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.4-100 500
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.38-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
$ apt-cache policy python-catkin-pkg
python-catkin-pkg:
  Installed: 0.4.2-100
  Candidate: 0.4.2-100
  Version table:
 *** 0.4.2-100 500
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.2.10-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292730/relationship-between-rospkg-and-catkin_pkg-(&-ament_package)/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2018-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without knowing what exact feature you would like to implement it is difficult to give a definitive answer.

In general I think it should likely go to `catkin_pkg`. `rospkg` is the "older" API which is still widely used in ROS 1.

While ROS 2 currently has `ament_package` we are actively moving the usage over to `catkin_pkg` since both packages have largely the same functionality. In the past it wasn't possible to use `catkin_pkg` because the Python 3 version wasn't side-by-side installable with the Python 2 version. That limitation has been resolved in the meantime in an effort to consolidate the two.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0